# I am getting error in PM2 for my nodejs app using loopback api after deploying

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, loopbackjs, amazon-elb, pm2

I have deployed my nodejs app which using loopback api. There are other two apps which are running using pm2 script in AWS Ec2.

I have tried with Stop pm2 and start it again, Kill the process and at last reboot the EC2 instance

After start pm2 ecosystem.config.js and after logged in form frontend it is showing following error:

```
  /home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/HGBackend-error.log last 15 lines:
  0|HGBacken |     at process._tickCallback 
  (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:3000
```

My ecosystem.config.js script is:

```
 module.exports = {
 apps : [
  {
    name      : "HGBackend",
    cwd       : "hgbackend/server",
    script    : "server.js",
    env_staging       :
     {
        "PORT": 3000,
        "NODE_ENV": "staging",
        "accesskeyAws":"123456"
    }
  },
  {
    name       : "HGBlockchain",
    cwd        : "hgblockchain/localgrammes",
    script     : "index.js"
    // args       : "start:staging"
   // instances  : 4,
   // exec_mode  : "cluster"
  },
  {
   name   : "HGWeb",
   cwd    : "hgweb/src/server",
   script : "server.js",
   //  env : {
  //  NODE_ENV: '.env.staging'
  //  },
 description: ""
     } 

 ]}
```

Application should run smoothly. application usrl is: http://app.honeygram.co which is using route 53 and redirecting through ELB

Answer (score 3):

The port which you are trying to use (i.e., 3000) is already in use. So try using another port.
OR

```
netstat -nlp | grep 3000
```

this command will give you the processID which was using port 3000, then kill it
`kill -9 <processID>`